# How to conditionally format a row of a table in Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization

I am new to DAX and I need help to colour the background of a row in table using DAX.

| Name | text |
| --- | --- |
| Book | Ora |
| Pencil | hjui |

I want to colour the entire row of table with Name = Book in Orange.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible using [conditional formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting).

In the `Fields` pane, right click your table and create the following measure:

```
Background color = IF(MAX('Table'[Name]) = "Book", "Orange", BLANK())
```

Then select the table visual and in `Visualizations` pane, right click each of the columns and select `Conditional formatting` -> `Background color`:

[image]

In `Format by` select `Field value` and select the above created measure in `Based on field`:

[image]

After you do that for each column shown, the result will be as follows:

[image]

Comment: Hi when I try to follow the steps you have mentioned when I apply the cponditional formatting based on field I get summarization

Comment: Most likely you selected a field from the table, not the measure.

Comment: Yes I did use a column of table

Comment: Then you must specify how to aggregate the value, because one row shown in the table can originate from multiple rows of data. That's what the `MAX` aggregate in the measure does. And the summarization there is very limited, so you will need a measure for that.